# Why Azure Staging feature replacing connection strings when i do Swap

Tags: azure, publish, azure-web-app-service

Here is full details about new [Azure Staging Feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/01/16/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance.aspx). And it says

> Some settings from the staged version will automatically copy to the
>   production version – including things like connection string
>   overrides, handler mappings, and other settings you might have
>   configured.  Other settings like the DNS endpoints, SSL bindings, etc
>   will not change (ensuring that you don’t need to worry about SSL certs
>   used for the staging domain overriding the production URL cert, etc).

What i don't understand is, it says connection strings are overrides. When i do swap connection strings, they swap each other. So in that case, my staging website database become production database. What i expect is, it doesn't touch connection strings at all and my production site will continue to use same database but it use staging database because connection string swap each other.

Is it possible to configure staging website for not to replace connection strings ?

It isn't wrong design by azure team that swapping cause to use test database on production website ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that is the design right now. AppSettings are just environment variables. To load different environment variables on a swap, that would require a process restart which will defeat one of the main requirements for this feature which is eliminating cold start time.

For now you can automate changing the staging database to the production one, and then hitting your site to warm it up right before you swap. But keep in mind that this feature is in preview now and some things are subject for change.

Comment: Who can have a use case for staging database that is turning into production database ? I assume that this feature is not designed to handle different website versions which has differences on database side so it fits just UI changes at the moment.

Comment: It's not that simple, whether Azure swaps the conneciton string or not, you will have to adapt your scenario to work with it.
Assume azure had a production connectionstr and a staging one, and they were sticky to the slot, meaning they don't get swapped. You then made changes on your vNext staging Db. You need to somehow get that update to the production database before you do a swap, otherwise the new code will be running on the old database. It ultimately depends on your particular scenario. It might help if you can describe your scenario more for me. different Dd Schema? test data in Db?

Comment: I use entity framework code first migrations so i use 2 database. When i swap, i expected my migrations is updated to on production database. This is my use case. Entity framework already automatically handles database changes when it is initialized but Azure is not designed in this way. You say "otherwise the new code will be running on the old database(schema)" but in this case new database(schema) will not have latest data updates from users.

Comment: EF Code First migration runs on app start. When you are publishing to a normal site, your site restarts and EF has a chance to run the migration and update your Db. If Azure Websites were to restart your process during a swap to pick up the new connection string and give EF a chance to run, this will defeat the 'no cold start' requirement. If it were to do it behind the scenes, warm it up, then do a swap, it might work, but will imply that the old code will be running on the new Db for a minute of 2. Managing artifacts that Azure Websites don't control (like Dbs) is tricky.

Comment: @ahmelsayed This helps clear it up for me. However, how would you recommend migrating a production db? If publishing directly to the production web site, the web site is cold and can lock up for a while. If migrating the production db from a staging web server, the production web server will lose access to the db and error. (Which I unfortunately discovered the hard way today.)